# rails 4.0.0.0 form helper jQuery Mobile data attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I want to use the jQuery Mobile datebox in time mode but can't figure out how to integrate the  rails input field helper with the jQuery Mobile data atrributes.

The fields are time fields. My form helper is type date as the TimeBox seems to require type date for the field.

What I have is

```
<%= f.date_field :start_time %>
```

What I need is to produce is the following but can't figure out how:

```
<input name="start_time" id="start_time" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox"}'>
```

migration:

```
t.time :start_time, :null => false
```

Comment: you maybe use formtastic, simpleform?

Comment: No, I am not using any form builders.

Comment: Two things. First change field type to text_field unless you want to have rails-generated selects. Second, just add `'data-role' => 'datebox', 'data-options' => '{"mode": "timebox"}'`!